# error when trying to hide a div

Tags: html, button, hide

I want to hide a div after a button is clicked which should be a pretty simple thing to do but I'm getting an error. I have the following code:

```
<div id="clearSale" onclick=playSound("sounds/Register.mp3") class="botonCLS">
      <button id="clearSaleBtn" type="button" style="position:relative; z-index:0; width: 90px; height: 32px; left: -6px; top: 0px;">Clear Sales</button>
```

```
<div id="check" style="display: none">
      <button id="confirm" style="margin-left: 5px">Send confirmation</button>
</div>
```

So What I want to do is replace the first one with the second one when the button is clicked..So typically enough, I added this line in a function in my JS which is called when I receive a push notification (which works):

`document.getElementByID("clearSaleBtn").style.display = "";`

But I am getting an error that the object does not support the method getelementbyid. I'm guessing that this might have something to do with the fact that the div is a class? Is there any way around this? Or is there a way to maybe change the text in the clear Sale button to send confirmation or something like that

Answer (score 2):

The Id section of the method name is camel cased.

```
document.getElementById("clearSaleBtn").style.display = "none";
```

instead of

```
document.getElementByID("clearSaleBtn").style.display = "none";
```

Also set the style to `display:none`;

Comment: @ Kevin Bowersox Thanks! Don't know how I missed that! I'm not getting an error now but for some reason the button isn't disappearing. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

the function name should be `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, javascript is case sensitive, so the function name is `getElementById`
    document.getElementById("clearSaleBtn").style.display = "none";

Secondly, use `"none"`as the new value, to hide the div.

Comment: Thanks completely forgot to use none!

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("clearSaleBtn").style.display = "";
```

You use `getElementByID` instead of `getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to change to button's text:

```
document.getElementById("clearSaleBtn").value="Send confirmation";
```

If you use it directly as the *onclick* action of your first button, you can shorten it to:

```
this.value="Send confirmation";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the function name to document.getElementById